# Task scheduling in Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, scheduled-tasks, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

My requirement is to schedule the reports at a particular time and frequency, i.e. weekly, monthly or daily.

This reports should be mailed at specified time with attachment at which it is scheduled.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use window scheduler. make exe in vb for fire mails and schedule it.

Comment: Have you looked at [Quartz.NET scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a great framework called Hangfire that you can use to schedule tasks in .net:

http://hangfire.io/

You'll need to create your method for running the report and sending the email but you can schedule that task easily with the hangfire framework.

For other alternatives take a look at this blog entry by Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: I have alredy tried this. But Not compatible with my framework.. Please suggest another way

Answer (score 0):

You could schedule tasks from within your ASP.NET project using the [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com) open source project.

Revalee is a service that allows you to schedule web callbacks to your web application. In your case, you would schedule a callback that would synchronize your data at a specific time. Revalee works very well with tasks that are discrete transactional actions, like updating some database values or sending an automated email message (read: not long running). The code to perform your action would all reside within your app.

To use Revalee, you would:

1. Install the Revalee Service, a Windows Service, on your server. The Windows Service is available in the source code (which you would compile yourself), in a precompiled version available at the [Revalee website](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com), or via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Revalee.Service).
2. Use the Revalee client library in your Visual Studio project. (There is an MVC-specific version too.) The client library is available in the source code (which, again, you would compile yourself) or in a precompiled version available via [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Revalee.Client/).
3. You would register a future callback when your code calls the `ScheduleReportTransmission()` method (this example is assuming that you need your action to run 12 hours from now, but it could be any date & time).

   ```
   Private Sub ScheduleReportTransmission()

       Dim callbackTime As DateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(12.0)

       ' The callback should be 12 hours from now
       Dim callbackUrl As New Uri("http://mywebapp.com/TransmitReport.aspx")

       ' Register the callback request with the Revalee service
       RevaleeRegistrar.ScheduleCallback(callbackTime, callbackUrl)

   End Sub
   ```
4. When Revalee calls your application back, your app would perform whatever action you have coded it to do. You do this by adding the following method call (`TransmitReport()`) to your `TransmitReport.aspx` page handler, à la:

   ```
   Private Sub TransmitReport()

       ' TODO Lookup the report information and send the email
       ' ...

       Return

   End Sub
   ```

I hope this helps.

Note: The code example above uses a synchronous version of `ScheduleCallback()`, the Revalee client library also supports asynchronous calls à la:

```
RevaleeRegistrar.ScheduleCallbackAsync(callbackTime, callbackUrl)
```

In case it was not clear above, the Revalee Service is not an external 3rd party online scheduler service, but instead a Windows Service that you install *and* fully control on your own network. It resides and runs on a server of your own choosing, most likely your web server (but this is not a requirement), where it can receive callback registration requests from your ASP.NET application.

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I was one of the developers involved with the Revalee project. To be clear, however, Revalee is free, open source software. The source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SageAnalytic/Revalee).</sub>